# How to use sideNav inside of o col ( instead of over the website )?

Tags: materialize

I'm trying to have a "sideNav" inside of a "col", so then each of the "cols" can have a "side panel" with options to be tweaked.

My template looks something like this:

```
  <div class="col s12 m12 l12">

    <i class="material-icons sidenavact" data-activates='slide-out1'>menu</i>  

    // my content here

    <ul id="slide-out1" class="side-nav right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>


  <div class="col s12 m12 l12">

    <i class="material-icons sidenavact" data-activates='slide-out2'>menu</i>  

    // my content here

    <ul id="slide-out2" class="side-nav right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
```

I initialise my button with:

```
$( col ).find('.sidenavact').sideNav( { closeOnClick: true, edge: 'right' } )
```

But unfortunately the SideNav is going over the whole website instead of limiting itself to the parent "col".

I tried using position: relative on the col, but that didn't work.

Any advice is more than appreciated.

EDIT ( have some progress ):

Switching the side-nav div position to "absolute" and parent to "relative" almost did the trick perfectly.

[image]

But there is still a couple of CSS issues:

1 - I don't need to block the webpage with that "black overlay" since the side-nav is meant to be contained in the "widget".

2 - "position: absolute" is making the side-nav show up over the "card shadow" and perhaps not respecting the padding created by the shadow as well?

Answer (score 0):

If I undertand it right you want to make 2 or more side navs on your code. to make that you need to change the size of you column.

`<div class="col s12 m6 l6">` try to make it less for tablet and desktop.

Comment: I just updated the example code to make it more self explainatory, regarding your suggestion, it is already inside of a col and changing the size of the col doesn't change the result. the sideNav will still be over the website and not limited inside of the parent col //=

Comment: you have any link to download it? i can try solve it  and post here to you

Comment: but i need to see the code to know what you are missing